# How do I sent database data safely from one computer to another?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with data in it and I need to duplicate the data and send it to another computer in a different country. What is the best way to do this safely?

Comment: What do you mean by "safely?"  Securely?  Without data corruption?  One time or often?

Comment: How big is the database? Do you need to do this once, sporadically, daily, near-real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can backup and restore data.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html

or you can sync data 
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling